# C++ Threads - pthread_create, pthread_join

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here? I am implementing pthread_create incorrectly

`int iret1 = pthread_create(&producer, NULL, produce, void*);`

`int iret2 = pthread_create(&consumer1, NULL, consume, void*);`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>

#define EMPTY 0
#define FILLED 1
#define BUFFER_SIZE 20

using namespace std;

//prototypes
void produce();
void consume(int);

int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

int main()
{


    int iret1 = pthread_create(&producer, NULL, produce, NULL);

    //join the threads



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using thread routine argument, just pass `NULL` pointer instead of `void*`:

```
pthread_create( &producer, NULL, produce, NULL );
```

The thread routine is supposed to be of `void* ()( void* )` type. Yours are different. It should be something like:

```
/// My fancy producer thread routine
extern "C" void* produce( void* arg ) {

    // do your thing here

    return 0; // or something if you want the result in pthread_join
}
```

Also, [`sleep(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/Sleep/) is not the greatest way of [thread synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29) :)

Comment: I got it. thanks. I was forgetting to change the function prototype as well and to compile with -lpthread

Answer (score 1):

Pass `NULL` as the fourth parameters, not `void *` (that's just its type).

Also, the type of the thread functions should be

```
void * produce(void *)
{...}
```

The are functions returning a void pointer and taking a parameter of a void pointer.

Comment: thanks, but I still get invalid conversion from void(*)() to void*(*)(void*)